# Unable to find if one item exists in array of items and return the necessary message in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have array of IDs. I have one ID which I want to find if that ID exists in the array of IDs in Perl

I tried the following code:

```
my $ids = [7,8,9];

my $id = 9;

foreach my $new_id (@$ids) {
   if ($new_id == $id) {
       print 'yes';
   } else {
       print 'no';
   }
}
```

I get the output as:

```
nonoyes
```

Instead I want to get the output as only:

```
yes
```

Since ID exists in array of IDs

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the else part and break the loop on finding the match:

```
my $flag = 0;
foreach my $new_id (@$ids) {
   if ($new_id == $id) {
       print 'yes';
       $flag = 1;
       last;
   }
}

if ($flag == 0){
    print "no";
}
```

Another option using hash:

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @$ids;
if (exists($hash{$id})){
    print "yes";
}else{
    print "no";
}
```

Comment: I want a no message if the array does not have the ID in case, so I need else condition

Comment: `if ($flag == 0)`? `if (!$flag)`!

Comment: Be careful, a hash uses string keys and thus does not represent all values that may be numerically equal (e.g. `0 == 0.0`, `0 == 0e0`)

Answer (score 5):

```
my $ids = [7,8,9];
my $id = 9;
if (grep $_ == $id, @ids) {
    print $id. " is in the array of ids";
} else {
    print $id. " is NOT in the array";
}
```

Comment: `@$ids`, not `@ids`.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw(any);   # core module

my $id = 9;
my $ids = [7,8,9];

my $found_it = any { $_ == $id } @$ids;

print "yes" if $found_it;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code should cover your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ids  = [7,8,9];
my $id   = 9;
my $flag = 0;

map{ $flag = 1 if $_ == $id } @$ids;

print $flag ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

NOTE: perhaps `my @ids  = [7,8,9];` is better way to assign an array to variable